# Plivo outbound call using Auth ID and Auth Token

Tags: android, plivo

I am using plivo Android SDK and trying plivo android example to make outbound call. It was successful to login and make call with my username and password of my account. But right now i just want to make a call using my AUTH_ID and AUTH_TOKEN, not username & password. Is that possible using android SDK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plivo Sales Engineer here.

Android and iOS SDKs use SIP Endpoints to make and receive calls. The endpoints are created against your Plivo account and while using Android/iOS SDKs in your app, it is required to use your SIP Endpoint username and password to register that endpoint with Plivo. It is not possible to use your Auth ID and Auth Token in the app to make calls.